# Node.js user system

Tags: node.js, authentication

I'm currently working on a web application which deals with multiple users. Whilst it currently works, it relies on some real bad practises which I'll outline in a minute.

*We're using MySQL as the database system, since we're updating our current application, we want to ensure everything is backwards compatible. Otherwise I'd look at MongoDB etc.*

Our users are stored in a table aptly named `login`. This contains their username, email, hashed password etc **and** a field which contains a JSON encoded object of their preferences.  There is no real reason for doing this over using a *meta* table.

So the bad practises:

- We're storing the entire users login row, excluding their password (although this is an internal-only app) in a cookie. It's  JSON encoded.
- Once the user logs in we have a secure HTTP cookie, readable only via Node.js for their username and their password so that we can continue to keep the user logged in automatically.
- We have a `app.get('*')` route which constantly ensures that the user has their three cookies and updates their `acc` cookie with new preferences. This means that every time the user switches page or accesses a new AJAX item (all under the same routes) they have an updated cookie.
- Every time a user performs an action we do this to get their user id: `JSON.parse(res.cookies.acc).agent_id` **yuck!**

Now, each user is able to perform actions to certain elements on the page, this effects everyone as the application is internal and anybody can work on the data inside of it.

I know what I want to achieve and how it should be done in say PHP, but I can't figure out the most effective way in Node.js.

I've started creating a *User* module which would allow us to get the user who performed the action and neatly update their preferences etc. You can see this [here](https://gist.github.com/jbrooksuk/7a9da9a37e04137716ed) bearing in mind that it's a WIP. The issue I'm having with the module is that it doesn't have access to the users cookies, since it's not "a part of" Express. Which explains the last bad practise.

What would be the best way to handle such a system and remain *bad-practise* free?

Comment: Do not store the password in a cookie.  Instead, sign the cookie so you know it came from your app.

Comment: It'a a secure cookie, `res.cookie('pass', account.pass,  { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 63072000000), httpOnly: true });`

Comment: Wrong; it's a slightly less insecure cookie.  1) You're storing the plaintext password in the browser's cookie DB. 2) You're sending the plaintext password on every request, without SSL.  3) You're involving the plaintext password at all.  4) Attackers can re-use the cookie after it "expires".

Comment: It certainly is, however I'm able to develop a better login system which fixes the issues I outlined above, this will no longer be an issue.

Comment: Don't use MD5; it is not secure.  Use bcrypt.

Comment: @SLaks I'm fully aware of the security faced and I appreciate you pointing it out to me, however if you could focus on the main issue at hand, this will fix these issues at the same time. Also, whilst it's MD5, it's hashed. It's an internal application used by few people on a server without external internet access.

Comment: It sounds like you are using Express. Have you looked at [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/)? I use it for authentication; once a user is logged in, passport assigns the user object to req.user, available in all routes. Express/passport also handles the cookies

Comment: @Plato thanks buddy! Assuming I can use `req.cookie` am I able to retrieve data from a user account and then write back to it?

Comment: In my project, if I want to modify a user, I first do `mydb.fetch(req.user.id, function(user){ ... }` and then I modify the `user` and do `mydb.stash(user)`. I don't know if Passport reloads the user on every request or only on session initialization.

Comment: Thanks Plato! I've started implementing Passport.js - logins work but the sessions don't remain when the user changes page. I'll continue looking.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it meets all of your requirements but its worth checking out out Drywall; A website and user system for Node.js

Hopefully it (or parts of it) could be helpful to you.

http://jedireza.github.io/drywall/